# Need Help Regarding MySQL IN Clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table named **collections** in which there are fields  **pk_collectionid** and **name**.

I am generating a string containing the collection ids separated by commas. Format is : `1,1`

I want to retrieve the name of all the ids mentioned in the string from  collections table.

I have used `IN clause under mysql`.

My query is:

```
SELECT name
FROM `collections`
WHERE `pk_collectionid`
IN ( 1, 1 )
```

Right now it is generating one row as id is common but i want that it should show two rows instead of one even if ids are same.

Comment: i think there is designproblem with the database. if an id is not unique ...

Comment: What is the index on this table? Is it unique perchance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very strange requirement. The only solution I could think of is to use a `UNION ALL` query:

```
SELECT name FROM `collections` WHERE `pk_collectionid` = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT name FROM `collections` WHERE `pk_collectionid` = 1
-- UNION ALL
-- SELECT name FROM `collections` WHERE `pk_collectionid` = 2
-- UNION ALL
-- SELECT name FROM `collections` WHERE `pk_collectionid` = 3
-- ...
```

Comment: Thanks salman for replying. The code suggested by you works fine but the issue is its static.  I will be running this query through php and i can pass the variable to in clause. For e.g. $collectionids=1,1  In query i will use select name from collections where pk_collectionid IN (.$collectionids.)

Comment: You can build a query in PHP just the way you build the string `1, 1`.

Comment: Thanks i used your suggestion and modified the query accordingly it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

You should not try to get duplicate rows back from the query -- it's not necessary, it's wasteful, and it's going to be a pain to implement.

Instead of doing this, create a map of `id` to a whole row from your result set. Then, you can iterate over the collection that includes duplicate ids (the one you used to construct the query in the first place) and use each id to index into the map you created. This way you will be able to process each record individually as many times as needed.

If you mentioned which language you are using, we could also give an example with code.

Comment: Thanks jon for replying. I am using php.            $collectionids=1,1;                                             select name from collections where pk_collectionid IN (.$collectionids.)

Comment: @Pankaj: What database access layer are you using? Show some code that takes the results and puts them into an array, or loops over them (whatever you have).